# Find the local maximum, minimum and saddle points of $f(x,y) = x + y + x^2y + xy^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, hessian-matrix

> Find the local maximum, minimum and saddle points of $f(x,y) = x + y + x^2y + xy^2$

$f_{xy} $ is not equal to $f_{yx} $, therefore nothing can be said about the critical points of this function.

Is this correct?

Comment: How have you come to the conclusion that $f_{xy} \neq f_{yx}$?

Comment: I miscalculated.

Comment: $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$ due to the symmetry has to be true. Clairaut Theorem.

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=1+2xy+y^2 \qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=1+2xy+x^2
$$
so
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\,\partial y }=2x +2y \qquad \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\,\partial x}=2x +2y
$$

so the mixed second derivative are equal and the problem does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

solve the equationsystem
$$1+2xy+y^2=0$$
$$1+x^2+2xy=0$$
for your function is hold $$-\infty<f(x,y)<\infty$$